# Increment pixels in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Im looking to increment pixel value in multiples of 100. I am using the @for loop in sass pulling the number of the div and multiplying that by 100.

It works great until I start exceeding 10. Because I want each batch of 10 to go from 100px to 1000px, but from 11 onward I end up with 1100px and up, which is too much.

Is there maybe a 100px++ in sass?

Hope this makes sense

Please view my sass function below

```
.horz {
        width:100px;
        height:10px;
        @for $i from 1 through 10 {
            &--#{$i} {
                margin-left:#{($i * 100)}px;
            }
        }
        @for $i from 11 through 20 {
            &--#{$i} {
                margin-top:100px;
                margin-left:#{($i * 100)}px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Desired CSS

```
    .horz {
        width: 100 px;
        height: 10 px;
    }

    .horz--1 {
        margin-left: 100 px;
    }

    .horz--2 {
        margin-left: 200 px;
    }
    .horz--3 {
        margin-left: 300 px;
    }
    .horz--4 {
        margin-left: 400 px;
    }
    .horz--5 {
        margin-left: 500 px;
    }
    .horz--6 {
        margin-left: 600 px;
    }
    .horz--7 {
        margin-left: 700 px;
    }
    .horz--8 {
        margin-left: 800 px;
    }
    .horz--9 {
        margin-left: 900 px;
    }
    .horz--10 {
        margin-left: 1000 px;
    }
```

Start from 100 again

```
    .horz--11 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 100 px;
    }
    .horz--12 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 200 px;
    }
    .horz--13 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 300 px;
    }
    .horz--14 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 400 px;
    }
    .horz--15 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 500 px;
    }
    .horz--16 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 600 px;
    }
    .horz--17 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 700 px;
    }
    .horz--18 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 800 px;
    }
    .horz--19 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 900 px;
    }
    .horz--20 {
        margin-top: 100 px;
        margin-left: 1000 px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just subtract 10 from `i` before multiplying?

```
    @for $i from 11 through 20 {
        &--#{$i} {
            margin-top:100px;
            margin-left:#{(($i - 10) * 100)}px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. But is this the best way of doing this?